# Bash awk one-liner not printing

Tags: bash, awk

Expecting this to print out abc - but I get nothing, every time, nothing.

```
echo abc=xyz | g="$(awk  -F "=" '{print $1}')" | echo $g
```

Comment: Quoting [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines): `Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell`. If you want to just print: `awk  -F "=" '{print $1}' <<< "abc=xyz"`.

Comment: Try ```g=$(echo abc=xyz | awk -F "=" '{print $1}') && echo $g```

Comment: I suggest: [Pipes: A Brief Introduction](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html)

Comment: @glennjackman That wouldn't work, because awk would have no input. It would just hang.

Comment: Of course. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

A pipeline isn't a set of separate assignments. However, you could rewrite your current code as follows:

```
result=$(
    echo 'abc=xyz' | awk -F '=' '{print $1}'
)
echo "$result"
```

However, a more Bash-centric solution without intermediate assignments could take advantage of a here-string. For example:

```
awk -F '=' '{print $1}' <<< 'abc=xyz'
```

Other solutions are possible, too, but this should be enough to get you started in the right direction.